# Change Values in a Dataframe from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the name of the below data frame as '`df1`'.

```
   Index   date            colum1          column2
      0       20200705        a              1.1%
      1       20200706        b              78%
      2       20200707        f              10%
      3       20200707        g              59%
      4       20200708        a              69%
      5       20200708        g              12%
```

Consider the name of the below data frame as '`df2`'.

```
     Index   date            colum1          column2
      0       20200707        q              11%
      1       20200707        w              54%
      2       20200708        e              64%
      3       20200708        r              11%
```

I want to update '`df1`' from '`df2`' by using the date column as condition. The dataframe below is my desired output.

```
  Index   date            colum1          column2
      0       20200705        a              1.1%
      1       20200706        b              78%
      2       20200707        q              11%
      3       20200707        w              54%
      4       20200708        e              64%
      5       20200708        r              11%
```

Comment: I see duplicates in the date column, if you set the index to ['date', 'column1']...will there be duplicate indexs?

Comment: What is the condition? You must be more explicit

Comment: Yes, there are duplicates in the date column

Comment: @gtomer, condition should be if df1['date'] = df2['date'] , then all the corresponding data of column 1 and column 2 for the matching dates of df1 should be replaced with data of df2

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df1a = df1[~df1['date'].isin(df2['date'].tolist())].copy() # Selects dates which are not in df2
df2a = df2[~df2['date'].isin(df1a['date'].tolist())].copy() # Selects dates which are not in df1a
df3 = df1a.append(df2a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code assumes the data frame are small sized, otherwise different ways need to be searched.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'date':['2020070{}'.format(i) for i in [5,6,7,7,8,8]],
    'column1':['a', 'b','f','g','a','g'],
    'column2':['{}%'.format(i) for i in [1.1,78,10,59,69,12]]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'date':['2020070{}'.format(i) for i in [7,7,8,8]],
    'column1':['q','w','e','r'],
    'column2':['{}%'.format(i) for i in [11,54,64, 11]]
})

dates_not_in_2 = [x for x in df1['date'] if x not in df2['date'].tolist()]
dates_common = [x for x in df1['date'] if x in df2['date'].tolist()]

combined = pd.concat([df1.loc[df1.date.isin(dates_not_in_2)], df2.loc[df2.date.isin(dates_common)]], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform your update it is not enough to align rows by the date alone.
The alignment should be "extended" by the "date index" - a consecutive
number for each date.

To compute these "date indices", for both source DataFrames, run:

```
df['dateInd'] = df.groupby('date').cumcount()
df2['dateInd'] = df2.groupby('date').cumcount()
```

Then perform the actual update and drop the above additional column:

```
df.set_index(['date', 'dateInd'], inplace=True)
df.update(df2.set_index(['date', 'dateInd']))
df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
       date colum1 column2
0  20200705      a    1.1%
1  20200706      b     78%
2  20200707      q     11%
3  20200707      w     54%
4  20200708      e     64%
5  20200708      r     11%
```